# Question about Proof of Cauchy's Theorem for Star Domain

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic on the domain $\Omega'$ which is obtained by deleting a finite number of points $\zeta_1,\ldots, \zeta_n\in \Omega$ from a star domain $\Omega$.  If the points $\zeta_j$ satisfy
>   $$\lim_{z\rightarrow \zeta_j}{(z-\zeta_j)f(z)}=0$$
>   for all $j$, then for any piecewise continuously differentiable closed curve $\gamma$ in $\Omega'$, we have
>   $$\int_\gamma{f(z)dz}=0.$$

Which is essentially a generalized form of Cauchy's Theorem for a Star Domain.  I have already proved the analogous result for when $\Omega$ is a triangle, and the points $\zeta_j$ are interior points of the triangle.

Thus, when no $\zeta_j$ is equal to the center of $\Omega$, say $z_0$, I may define
$$F(z)=\int_{[z_0,z]}{f(z)dz}$$
where $[z_0,z]$ is the line segment joining $z_0$ to $z$ (with positive orientation), which exists because $\Omega$ is a star domain, and $z\in \Omega'$.  Because $\Omega$ is open, there is an open ball about $z$, say with radius $r$, and thus if I pick $|h|<r$, and also small enough so that for any point in the closed ball of radius $|h|$ centered at $z$, the line segment joining that point to $z_0$ does not contain any of the points $\zeta_j$ (possible because there are finitely-many of them).  Then using the result for Cauchy's Theorem for a Triangle (generalized in the above way), I may conclude that
$$F(z+h)-F(z)=\int_{[z,z+h]}{f(z)dz}.$$
I can then use this to show that $F(z)$ is analytic at $z$ with derivative $F'(z)=f(z)$, from which the result follows.

However, as stated above, I made the assumption that $z_0$ is not any of the points $\zeta_j$, which was a necessary assumption for the above argument since the result I quote concerning Cauchy's Theorem for Triangles holds when the points $\zeta_j$ are *interior* points of the triangle.  But if $\zeta_j=z_0$ for some $j$, then the triangle I make use of in the above proof has a $\zeta_j$ on the boundary, and the theorem does not apply.

Is there a way fix the proof for the case when it is possible that $z_0$ is one of the $\zeta_j$? (Without proving the general Cauchy's Theorem, of course)

EDIT:
A **star domain** is a set $S$ in which there exists an element $z_0\in S$ called the *center* such that for every element $z$ of $S$ the line segment $[z,z_0]$ lies entirely within $S$.  In the above I make the additional assumption that star domains are also open in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I don't know what's your definition of star domain, but if it allows you to jiggle the centre about in a little disk then you can avoid finitely many points.

Comment: @user21820 I edited the question with a definition.  That was my initial idea, but it didn't pan out, as can be seen here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804696/open-star-domains-with-only-finite-set-of-centers

Comment: Seems like an inconvenient way to go about it. If for the local version of Cauchy's theorems you use convex sets (even proving them only for disks suffices), the difficulties disappear. And if you suppose that $f$ is continuous in the $\zeta_j$, the difficulties disappear too. Well, too late, I guess. You can take a small disk around $z_0$ lying in $\Omega$ such that it contains no other $\zeta_j$, pick a point $z_1$ in that disk, and use a path consisting of line segments in the disk (avoiding $z_0$) and the part of $[z_0,z]$ outside the disk to define $F$.